# Looking for a name for this flawed argument "tactic"

Tags: argumentation, debate

What is it called when you're in an argument with someone about some relatively small thing, and they bring up an overarching out-of-your control thing that if things go wrong, the smaller argument is moot? Something something blah blah fallacy? It's on the tip of my tongue.

For example: arguing with a coworker about respecting personal space, and the one who doesn't care about it (trying to argue against the need for it for some other value like organization/cleanliness) brings up "well, if we don't have enough sales and lose our jobs and can't afford this office it's not going to matter!"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a [red-herring](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/150/Red-Herring), or *[ignoratio elenchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi)* (i.e. an ignoring of a refutation)?

> Attempting to redirect the argument to another issue that to which the person doing the redirecting can better respond. While it is similar to the [avoiding the issue fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/61/Avoiding-the-Issue), the red herring is a deliberate diversion of attention with the intention of trying to abandon the original argument.

In your case it sounds like [non-sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)) (i.e. it does not follow) followed by opinion.